# Calculating average of a value for X number of weeks in a table with weekly entries in Azure Data Explorer - Any option other than self join?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I have a table where every row is from a week. There are multiple rows for the same week but they are unique based on a couple of dimensions.

```
| Week | Col1 | Col2 |
----------------------
|  W1  |  X1  |   a  |
|  W1  |  X2  |   b  |
|  W2  |  X3  |   a  |
.
... More rows
```

I want to calculate the average value of `Col1` over a period of 4 weeks (or in general, X weeks).

I know I can do that by joining the table with itself 4 times but it just doesn't seem right... Is there a better way to do it?

Sample input datatable:

```
datatable (Week:datetime, Value:decimal  , Dim1:string)
    [datetime(2020-08-03), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-03), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "c",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 2, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 4, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-31), 3, "c"]
```

My desired result would be (in this example I use the last day as the "day" of the average). Note that when there is no value in a week I assume it is `0`. Furthermore, if a dimension appears in one of the weeks it is included in the final average (not expected to happen but adding this for completeness):

```
| Week       | Average_Value | Dim1 |
-------------------------------------
| 2020-08-03 | 0.25          | a    | <-- backfill with zeroes
| 2020-08-03 | 0.5           | b    |
| 2020-08-10 | 0.5           | a    |
| 2020-08-10 | 0.75          | b    |
| 2020-08-17 | 1             | b    |
| 2020-08-17 | 0.5           | c    |
| 2020-08-27 | 1             | a    |
| 2020-08-27 | 2.25          | b    |
| 2020-08-27 | 0.5           | c    | <-- has average values even with no value in week
| 2020-08-31 | 0.75          | a    | <-- has average values even with no value in week
| 2020-08-31 | 1.75          | b    | <-- has average values even with no value in week
| 2020-08-31 | 1.25          | c    |
-------------------------------------
```

This is how I did it with joins:

```
let Test = datatable (Week:datetime, Value:real, Dim1: string)
    [datetime(2020-08-03), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-03), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "c",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 4, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 2, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-31), 3, "c"];
let FullTable = Test
| summarize by Week
| extend A = 1
| join kind=fullouter (Test | summarize by Dim1 | extend A = 1) on A
| join kind=leftouter (Test) on Week, Dim1
| project-away Week1, Dim11, A, A1;
FullTable
| join kind=leftouter (FullTable | extend Week = Week + 7d) on Week, Dim1
| join kind=leftouter (FullTable | extend Week = Week + 14d) on Week, Dim1
| join kind=leftouter (FullTable | extend Week = Week + 21d) on Week, Dim1
| project Week, Dim1, Value0 = iff(isnull(Value), 0.0, Value), Value1 = iff(isnull(Value1), 0.0, Value1), Value2 = iff(isnull(Value2), 0.0, Value2), Value3 = iff(isnull(Value3), 0.0, Value3)
| extend Average = (Value0 + Value1 + Value2 + Value3)/4
| project-away Value0, Value1, Value2, Value3
```

It does the trick but it seems there should be a *better* way.

Comment: How is the week encoded? Is it a datetime or a string? Are you looking for exactly four weeks or per month? Can you provide a datatable with the expected input and a table with the expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see 2 suggestions below, "inspired" by [aggregations over sliding window](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/samples#perform-aggregations-over-a-sliding-window). The idea is to expand every value to the end of the analyzed period (28d).

```
let _start = datetime(2020-08-03);
let _period = 28d;
let _end = _start + 28d; 
let Test = datatable (Week:datetime, Value:real, Dim1: string)
    [datetime(2020-08-03), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-03), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "c",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 4, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 2, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-31), 3, "c"];
Test 
| order by Dim1 asc, Week asc 
| extend _bin = bin_at(Week, 7d, _start) 
| extend _endRange = iif(_bin + _period > _end, _end, 
                            iff( _bin + _period - 7d < _start, _start,
                                iff( _bin + _period - 7d < _bin, _bin,  _bin + _period - 7d)))  
| extend _range = range(_bin, _endRange, 7d) 
| mv-expand _range to typeof(datetime) 
| extend WeekNum = toint((_range - Week)/7d)
| project Week=_range, Dim1, Value, WeekNum=strcat("Value",WeekNum)
| evaluate pivot(WeekNum, sum(Value))
| project Week, Dim1, Average = (Value0 + Value1 + Value2 + Value3)/4
```

```
|Week|Dim1|Average|
|---|---|---|
|2020-08-03 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.25|
|2020-08-03 00:00:00.0000000|b|0.5|
|2020-08-10 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.5|
|2020-08-10 00:00:00.0000000|b|0.75|
|2020-08-17 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.5|
|2020-08-17 00:00:00.0000000|b|1.25|
|2020-08-17 00:00:00.0000000|c|0.5|
|2020-08-24 00:00:00.0000000|a|1|
|2020-08-24 00:00:00.0000000|b|2.25|
|2020-08-24 00:00:00.0000000|c|0.5|
|2020-08-31 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.75|
|2020-08-31 00:00:00.0000000|b|1.75|
|2020-08-31 00:00:00.0000000|c|1.25|
```

Option #2:

```
let _start = datetime(2020-08-03);
let _period = 28d;
let _end = _start + 28d; 
let Test = datatable (Week:datetime, Value:real, Dim1: string)
    [datetime(2020-08-03), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-03), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-10), 1, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-17), 2, "c",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 4, "b",
     datetime(2020-08-24), 2, "a",
     datetime(2020-08-31), 3, "c"];
let _dims = Test | distinct Dim1;
let _fullRange = range Week from _start to _end step 7d 
 | extend _start = max_of(-3, -((Week-_start)/7d))
 | extend _range = range((_start), (_start+3), 1) | mv-expand _range to typeof(int) | project Week, _origin = Week + _range*7d | extend K=1, Value=0.0 ;
let _fullRangeDims = _dims | extend K=1 | join kind=inner (_fullRange) on K | project-away K;
_fullRangeDims
| join kind=fullouter
(Test 
| order by Dim1 asc, Week asc 
| extend _bin = bin_at(Week, 7d, _start) 
| extend _endRange = iif(_bin + _period > _end, _end, 
                            iff( _bin + _period - 7d < _start, _start,
                                iff( _bin + _period - 7d < _bin, _bin,  _bin + _period - 7d)))  
| extend _range = range(_bin, _endRange, 7d) 
| mv-expand _range to typeof(datetime) 
| project Week=_range, Dim1, Value, _origin = Week) on Week, _origin, Dim1
| project Week=coalesce(Week1, Week), Dim1=coalesce(Dim11, Dim1), Value=coalesce(Value1, Value), _origin= coalesce(_origin1, _origin)
| summarize avg(Value) by Week, Dim1
| order by  Week asc, Dim1 asc
```

```
|Week|Dim1|avg_Value|
|---|---|---|
|2020-08-03 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.25|
|2020-08-03 00:00:00.0000000|b|0.5|
|2020-08-03 00:00:00.0000000|c|0|
|2020-08-10 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.5|
|2020-08-10 00:00:00.0000000|b|0.75|
|2020-08-10 00:00:00.0000000|c|0|
|2020-08-17 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.5|
|2020-08-17 00:00:00.0000000|b|1.25|
|2020-08-17 00:00:00.0000000|c|0.5|
|2020-08-24 00:00:00.0000000|a|1|
|2020-08-24 00:00:00.0000000|b|2.25|
|2020-08-24 00:00:00.0000000|c|0.5|
|2020-08-31 00:00:00.0000000|a|0.75|
|2020-08-31 00:00:00.0000000|b|1.75|
|2020-08-31 00:00:00.0000000|c|1.25|
```

Comment: Interesting solution. Performance wise, is there any preference? Because readability wise I still prefer my solution :-)

Comment: The performance depends on your data set, it's best to test both options. The option I suggested requires serialization of all data (due to the order by), and also executes the query twice (due to the pivot plugin) so on large data sets it may not perform as well as your option. I edited the reply and added another suggestion which may perform better than both options (and may also hopefully be more readable).